# How to handle file upload using Angular2 Formbuilder?

Tags: angular, file-upload, typescript2.0, angular2-formbuilder

It seems as if there is dearth of proper documentation at Angular Docs. Angular2 final release is still younger so there isn't much help available on the internet.

I'll appreciate if someone can guide me to a way to handle file uploads using FormBuilder component in **Angular 2.1**

Answer (score 0):

Quick and gets the job done (modify to suit your needs):

```
// Inside component
fileUploaded(event: any) {
    const file = event.srcElement.files[0];
    this.form.get('file').patchValue(file);
}

// Inside template
<input type="file" (change)="fileUploaded($event)">
```